# finding encoding type using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, character-encoding

I have a requirement that my batch script should find whether the encoding type of input file to batch process is either UTF-8 or not?Can anyone suggest me any idea whether we can find the encoding type or not in windows??

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? I ask this because you can easily convert the files before processing them but actually determining what encoding they are is a bit more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If the file is in UTF-8 format, i can use the file as it is.But when the file is in different format,I need to convert the file into UTF-8 and need to process.So for that i need to know the file format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `certutil` you can dump file in hex format. UTF-8 files begins with `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`  . So:

`certutil -dump my.file.txt | find "ef bb bf" && echo this is utf-8`

You can put this in `FOR /F` loop to be sure that only the first line is processed.

**update:**

It turned out that the `-dump` option of `certutil` is [buggy](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6588#p6588).So I needed to use the `-encodehex` which requires one temporary file:

```
@echo off
:detect_encoding
setLocal
if "%1" EQU "-?" (
    endlocal
    call :help
    exit /b 0
)
if "%1" EQU "-h" (
    endlocal
    call :help
    exit /b 0
)
if "%1" EQU "" (
    endlocal
    call :help
    exit /b 0
)


if not exist "%1" (
    echo file does not exists
    endlocal
    exit /b 54
)

if exist "%1\" (
    echo this cannot be used against directories
    endlocal
    exit /b 53
)

if "%~z1" EQU "0" (
    echo empty files are not accepted
    endlocal
    exit /b 52
)



set "file=%~snx1"
del /Q /F "%file%.hex" >nul 2>&1 

certutil -f -encodehex %file% %file%.hex>nul

rem -- find the first line of hex file --

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%E in ("%file%.hex") do (
    set "f_line=%%E" > nul
    goto :enfdor
)
:enfdor
del /Q /F "%file%.hex" >nul 2>&1 

rem -- check the BOMs --
echo %f_line% | find "ef bb bf"     >nul && echo utf-8     &&endlocal && exit /b 1
echo %f_line% | find "ff fe 00 00"  >nul && echo utf-32 LE &&endlocal && exit /b 5
echo %f_line% | find "ff fe"        >nul && echo utf-16    &&endlocal && exit /b 2
echo %f_line% | find "fe ff 00"     >nul && echo utf-16 BE &&endlocal && exit /b 3
echo %f_line% | find "00 00 fe ff"  >nul && echo utf-32 BE &&endlocal && exit /b 4

echo ASCII & endlocal & exit /b 6



endLocal
goto :eof

:help
echo.
echo  %~n0 file - Detects encoding of a text file
echo.
echo for each encoding you will recive a text responce with a name and a errorlevel codes as follows:

echo     1 - UTF-8
echo     2 - UTF-16 BE
echo     3 - UTF-16 LE
echo     4 - UTF-32 BE
echo     5 - UTF-32 LE
echo     6 - ASCII

echo for empty files you will receive error code 52
echo for directories  you will receive error code 53
echo for not existing file  you will receive error code 54
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Your answer is really helpful for me.I have another doubt that for other encoding file types like unicode and etc,can you specify the changes to be done to find the file type??

Comment: here you can find info for other utf encodings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark  .I'm not sure it will work in all cases.

Comment: In earlier post you have mentioned under the topic "Reading few bytes from file and writing to text file using batch" the answer is  "with this command cerutil -decodehex myfile myfile.hex you can see your file in hex , and then process it.With encodehex you can convert a hex data into text.This command is not working for conversion of a text file in to hex format.Can i use "cerutil -decodehex myfile myfile.hex" script for converting to hex format and find whether it is UTF-8 or ansi format?

Comment: with `-decodehex` you can convert hex to binary/test/etc...ANSI should be in general ASCII that uses extended character set and visualization may differ depending in localization.The script above (the second) uses exactly the `-encodehex` option to find the encoding of the file (ASCII is detected too)

Comment: With -encodehex,my file is not able to predict the encoding format.Can you specify where to give the file name and its path in the above query?.By using -dump,it finds only the UTF-8 file.but fot unicode big endian file i have changed the -dump code to both UTF-16 LE and BE.But it is not working for unicode big endian files.

Comment: Yes.That a bug in -dump command - It does not work with Unocode (utf16) files. Have you tested the script above? With `certutil -encodehex %file% %file%.hex` i'm creating a temporary file in hex format.Then I'm checking the first line for encoding BOMs (in for loop I'm getting the first line , and then i'm using find to check the BOMs).You just have to pass the file name / location as a first parameter to the script.

Comment: In the update script you have mentioned,Where to specify the file location and file name??In that code you have tested 4 IF statements...What is the use of those??

Comment: file is defined here `set "file=%~snx1"`  - %1 is just the first argument passed to the script.The four IF statements check if the first argument is `-?` or `-help` or.. and in this case the script will print the help message

Comment: Instead of %~snx1 i need to give my file path and file name..Do i need to make any other changes?

Comment: you don't need to change anything.Just save this as a enc.detector.bat      (e.g) and call it `c:\>enc.detector.bat some.file`

Comment: In the code ,till the conversion of hex file it is working fine.But after that checking the hex code is not executing.

Comment: I think I've found the issue.Spaces after the line number in the encoded file might vary.Now I'm checking only the BOMS. There are aditionals checks for file existance and I'm not typing the whole hex file - now also should be faster.Could you check it now?

Comment: The BOM signature at the beginning of the UTF file is optional, and not recommended anymore. This answer could use an update if not a warning.